# Theme Development : License help

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm developing my WordPress Theme.

Is Theme required to use Copy Right when its does not have registered in Copy Righted list?

is themes images directory required Copy Right declaration?

I checked many WordPress does not provide Copy Right info and also does not declare copy right declaration that used in theme.

Comment: What do you mean by "Copy Righted list" precisely? De-facto situation in many countries is that copyright over creation is inherent and doesn't need to be registered. If in your country such registration is needed — you are best to talk to local lawyer about it. In any case it's natural to supply information about theme's copyright/license state, whatever it is.

Comment: Like Copyrighted by Cpanel , Windows etc.